# Sumar columnas usando for en RStudio

Tags: r, bucle-for, dataframe, rstudio

Tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero llegar a la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es si puedo sumar columnas que tengan un mismo patrón, en este caso el nombre donde solo cambia el número, usando un for.

Tengo este código, con el cual esperaba sumar las columnas de manera automática

```
nombres = c('columna1','columna2','columna3')
for (i in nombres) {
     tablaprueba$i = c(0,0)
}
```

pero el resultado que obtengo es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero alguno pueda aconsejarme al respecto para conseguir la adición de más de una columna usando for.

> La idea es agregar varias columnas de manera automatizada. Por
> ejemplo, si debo agregar 50 columnas, cuyos nombres son columna1,
> columna2,...,columna50, cómo poder hacerlo de manera simple y rápida

Comment: No me queda del todo claro lo que estás preguntando, ¿será algo como esto: `colSums(tablaprueba[, c('columna1','columna2','columna3')])`?

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho. Lo que quiero hacer es agregar varias columnas usando un for o algo similar. La idea es agregar varias columnas de manera automatizada. Por ejemplo, si debo agregar 50 columnas, cuyos nombres son columna1, columna2,...,columna50, cómo poder hacerlo de manera simple y rápida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con un ciclo:

```
nuevas_columnas <- paste0("columnas_", 1:3)
for (columna in nuevas_columnas) {
  df[columna] <- 0
}
```

O mucho mejor de forma vectorial:

```
nuevas_columnas <- paste0("columnas_", 1:3)
df[nuevas_columnas] <- 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio. Tu respuesta era justo lo que necesitaba para seguir avanzando con mi código.